# Rewrite HTTP POST request from AngularJS to Angular4

Tags: angularjs, angular, spring-mvc, typescript

I have to rewire my http post request from angularJS, which was written like so:

```
function removeExtension(ext){
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'remove',
                params: { removeExt: ext
                }
            }).then(function(resp){
                console.log('Its was successfull');
            });
        }
```

Now I have to write it in Angular4, inside a HostListener like so:

```
@HostListener("click", ['$event'])
   onDropdownItemClick( evt: MouseEvent) {
       console.log('clicked with ' + evt.ctrlKey);
       if (evt.ctrlKey){
           //http request here
           //this.menuItem.id should be sent via http post
       }
```

This is what I have in my java code:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   public String getExtensionToRemove(@RequestParam(value = "removeExt", required=false) String ext){
      _extensionService.setExtension(ext);
      return null;
   }
```

How can this be achieved and also how can I add a refresh event after the response has been returned? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Http client](https://angular.io/guide/http) something like

```
 return this.http.post("/remove", {removeExt: ext}).toPromise()
            .then(response => {
//do something after response 
})
            .catch(err =>{
//catch error here
});
```

[Here you can find some good example for http client](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-post-example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get is as null in my java controller, this is because it is sent as a promise, not as a query string parameter, any idea how to send it as one?

Comment: I see as per this post https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/core-http-api/#_post_with_data that an object is passed, not a query string parameter, my question then is how to modify the backend to get the string (ext) that I'm passing? Or is there a way to pass it directly by editing the angular post request?